# Androidx86 touch screen not working. I have no idea what to do

Tags: android-x86

I tried to do a lot of research on this but couldn't solve the issue. I have tried installing android 6.0 r3, 7.1rc1, 6.0 r2 (64bits all of them) from this link http://www.android-x86.org/download. It a windows tablet which intel 64 based processor. Installation is successful, but touchscreen is not working. Only keyboard works. Anyone, can have some suggestions or answers? 
Sorry by the way, if this question is not according to the standard but I have come here after i couldn't really solve it.

Comment: In my case the screen works, but the clicks get seem registered at the wrong places, is yours the same? Maybe you solved it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the fix. (All commands are in the quotes and Linux is case sensative, so please copy exactly.

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to go into Terminal mode. (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> will switch back to the GUI)
   Type in `stop zygote` and press <kbd>enter</kbd> (This will stop the Android GUI)
2. Type in `mkdir /data/system/tslib` and <kbd>enter</kbd>enter (This should make a directory/folder called *tslib* inside */data/system*
3. Type in `cd /data/system` and press <kbd>enter</kbd> (This will change the current directory to */data/system*
4. Type in `ls` and press <kbd>enter</kbd> (This will list all files and folders in the current Directory)
5. Check to see if your new directory, **tslib** is listed.
6. Type in `ts_calibrate` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>

   - This should load up the calibration tool and you should have a **X** in the top left to press, when you do, you are moved to the top right, then bottom right, then bottom left and finally the centre of the screen.
7. Type in `cd tslib` and press <kbd>enter</kbd> (This should move you into your new tslib directory you made earlier)
8. Type in `ls` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>(You should see a file in there called pointercal, which was created by the calibration tool)
9. Finally, type in `start zygote` and press <kbd>enter</kbd> (This will load up the GUI again along with your new calibration settings)