# ts_calibrate not found android X86

Tags: android, x86

After following a few guides ([Androidx86 touch screen not working. I have no idea what to do](https://superuser.com/questions/1245664/androidx86-touch-screen-not-working-i-have-no-idea-what-to-do/1474230#1474230?newreg=c3e443c3c91b417ab547a1e8f000b3de)) I am able to create the folder but no calibration. This is the kitkat version. Other version all have the same issue that I have tested. depending on the version when i run stop zygote I either boot back to the android start logo and it get stuck or nothing happens. Any help here would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Type Alt + F1  again to get back.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.